# Trigger any event type no matter how it has been attached to an element

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

After finding out that there is no `change` method on elements that will trigger a `change` event in the same way that the `click` method on elements will trigger a `click` event, I'm now looking for a way to fire an event as if the event had actually been carried out. This means that event handlers that have been setup to handle an event through these ways must execute:

- Handlers associated with an element using HTML attributes such as `onclick`, `onchange`, `onmousedown`.
- Handlers attached to an object by setting an `on*` method (i.e., `onclick`, `onchange`, etc.).
- Handlers attached to an object using `addEventListener`.

In searching for answer to this, I did turn up `dispatchEvent` and `initEvent`, sometimes used in conjunction, but documentation for either of these methods says that they are deprecated; I don't know if there is any more up-to-date substitute. Also, this solution should be cross-browser.

If `dispatchEvent`/`initEvent` is the only solution, then I'll use it, but I'd like to know why people are suggesting it even though it's "deprecated". If I were writing DOM standards, then I'd make this look like `Element.prototype.doEvent(eventTypeName)`.

Comment: *"...there is no `change` method on elements that will trigger a `change` event in the same way that the `click` method on elements will trigger a `click` event,"* ....whahht??

Comment: `HTMLElement.click()` (and `.blur()`, and `.focus()`) are convenience functions, shorthand for creating a specific kind of common event and dispatching it. If you need to trigger some other event, create it with something like `let someEvent = new Event('change')`, and then dispatch it with something like `targetElement.dispatchEvent(someEvent)`. This is described in [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events).

Comment: @zer00ne `typeof document.createElement("select").change` returns `"undefined"`.

Comment: @Ouroborus But not all browsers support that method.

Comment: @Melab `.dispatchEvent()` has pretty good support. What browser do you need to support for that isn't in the [compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent#Browser_Compatibility)?